# How can a boost PFC (Vienna rectifier) lower the voltage?

Tags: rectifier, power-factor-correction

I found a [Vienna rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_rectifier) circuit as a PFC.

[image]

Output range: +350...+500VDC and -350...-500VDC.
Input: 400VAC (three phases).

To begin with, I simulated a basic three-phase rectifier:
[image]

Here's the 561V output.

This is more than the 350V minimum from the Vienna rectifier.

I concluded that the Vienna rectifier has a buck mode in addition to boost mode. But before that, I already received an answer that the Vienna rectifier works only in Boost mode.

After that, I got stuck. It is not clear to me how this circuit can provide a drop to 350V when entering 400VAC.

The only thing I assumed is that two series capacitors with a midpoint - form a voltage divider.
Almost everywhere where the Vienna rectifier circuit is shown - only the maximum output voltage is indicated, the minimum I saw only in this circuit.

**Questions:**

1. How is the output voltage drop achieved in this topology?
2. The maximum output is 500VDC, but I have seen identical circuits with outputs of 750 VDC, 840 VDC and more. Does the value of the input inductances affect here? Or is this voltage limited only by the parameters of the components (switches, diodes, capacitors)?

Thank you!

Comment: The Vienna rectifier produces 700 volts DC minimum. You forgot about the minus 350 volts and that is there whether you want to ignore it or not.

Comment: @Andy aka, Thank you for the answer! After a while, I delved deeper into the topology of PFC converters and realized that the minimum output is really 700V (Between + 350V and -350V). There is also a center GND tap. Between it and the buses + -350V. For example, this can be used to further connect to a dual LLC converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a Vienna rectifier is it integrates both active rectification and boost topology.  In your simulation, you ignore the 2 crucial components: the inductor and back-to-back FETs. When the \$\left|\frac{dV}{dt}\right|\rightarrow0\$, the inductor is sourcing current. This continuity of current allows the capacitors to be charged up further, resulting in a higher DC voltage (much like a regular [boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) converter).

Vienna rectifier is boost-only. For a buck variant, check out a [Swiss](https://doi.org/10.1109/APEC.2012.6166192) rectifier. You might also find these papers useful:

- [The Essence of Three-Phase PFC Rectifier Systems - Part I](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPEL.2012.2197867)
- [The Essence of Three-Phase PFC Rectifier Systems - Part II](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPEL.2013.2258472)